# Overriding CSS in link file with code in HEAD

Tags: html, css

EDIT: Code works, apparently I failed to notice a typo. Sorry guys.

There are some CSS rules that I would like to override on certain pages. This is an example of how I would like to achieve it. Is this a valid approach? It does not seem to work in my browsers.

main.css:

```css
#header {
    background-color: yellow;
    color: #003300;
    height: 65px;
    margin-top: 5px;
    padding: 10px 0 10px;
}
```

index.html

```
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/main.css" />

<style>
    #header {
        background-color: red;
    }
</style>
</head>
```

Comment: It *should* work. Can you show a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net), please?

Comment: It works. I just realized that a typo was breaking my code.

Comment: yea I was checking for typo but you had it correct on here haha

Answer (score 2):

There is this sense of inheritance with CSS.

I actually like another link css tag after the one you already have that has the #header in it the way you want..

An interesting interview question is why are cascading stylesheets called so...Why aren’t they just called Style Sheets.

It's because of the way you can override stylesheets.  The bottom most stylesheet that has the class in it that you are referencing is the one used.

You can also put the style right in the place you want it and override the css there.

Answer (score 1):

That should be able to work. You probably need more info in your `style` tag. Try this:

```
<style type="text/css">
#header {
    background-color: red;
}
</style>
```

Comment: type should be added but I don't think it makes a difference, at least in my experience

Answer (score 1):

Inline styling is not the best approach.

Try wrapping the page content in a div and then selecting the container and the header div as one:

```
<div class="my-page">
    <div id="header">header</div>
</div>

.my-page #header { background-color:pink; }
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
#header {
    background-color: yellow;
    color: #003300;
    height: 65px;
    margin-top: 5px;
    padding: 10px 0 10px;
}
```

Not sure if this is the problem, but your second padding parameter doesn't have a `px` after it. It could be causing the parser to error out. Give that a try and let us know from there.

Comment: No, a `0` is unambiguous. Not the issue.

Comment: That is the correct syntax for a 0 value. You shouldn't put px/em or whatever if the value is 0

Comment: I've had issues before where I left it as a 0 and as soon as I added the 'px' things cleared up. I know there's correct syntax and a standard, but sometimes things just work differently. This is just my experience though.